# Oracle Apex Task Error APEX.TASK.RELEASE_TASK_NOT_AUTHORIZED

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am currently facing some challenges with the multilevel workflow approval in my Apex application, and I was hoping to seek your guidance and expertise in resolving the following issues:

i) When attempting to cancel a task that has not been completed using the 'Cancel Task' button, I encounter the error message 'APEX.TASK.RELEASE_TASK_NOT_AUTHORIZED'. I am unsure of the cause behind this error and would appreciate any insights or suggestions you may have.

ii) As an Approver, I encounter a similar error message, 'APEX.TASK.RELEASE_TASK_NOT_AUTHORIZED', when trying to approve a task from the task detail page. However, I have noticed that I am able to approve the request successfully from My approval screen. This inconsistency in the error occurrence is perplexing, and I am struggling to identify the root cause.

Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: What version of APEX?  I believe they have made several updates to the task API recently.